# Do the fetishes spawned from Fetish Sycophants match elements with the skill?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Fetish Sycophants randomly spawns fetishes when I attack, do those fetishes match the element of the Fetish army skill?  I am using Tiki Torchers since I have + fire element gear.

Comment: I know that they share your crit damage and crit chance. I'm not sure about the elemental damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Fetish Army damage will change with runes (i.e. Tiki Torches will change all FA fetishes to fire damage, even the melee ones), Fetish Sycophants are always physical damage (unless you use [Carnevil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/carnevil)).

[Here is an excellent guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091749472?page=1) on Fetishes and Fetish builds.

[Another thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12412051196#1) detailing fetish damage, including verification of the all physical/poison conversion for Carnevil damage types of Fetish Sycophants.

Comment: nvm nice guide it has all the answers in it, ty